# Is Ireland visa appeal effect to the German student visa

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, study, ireland

I applied for an Ireland visa under Conference/Event sometime back. My visa not rejected but I had to appeal with some documents. But I did not appeal because my conference's deadline was passed. The Ireland consulate stamped on my passport as applied.

Now I am planning to apply for a German student visa and I want to know whether my previous visa status effect to the current visa application process?

Comment: The German authorities will evaluate your application according to the data you supplied and also query databases. There is no *automatic* rejection due to your history, and the student visa process will look at different criteria. The Irish officials might have **worried** that you want to immigrate illegally, the German authorities **know** that you want to stay for a long time and evaluate your application on that basis.